# Obtaining danceability and valence using spotipy

Tags: spotipy

Is there a method that gets the danceability and valence of a song on Spotify using spotipy?

I do not see anything on the spotipy documentation, but I was wondering if there was any other way to get those values.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is, it's called `audio_features()`

I suggest you to use Web API Reference to find method for your needs & try them
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#endpoint-get-audio-features

And then find the method corresponding on spotipy documentation
https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/#spotipy.client.Spotify.audio_features